# How to stop AutoMounter from trying Network Shares on High Sierra?

Tags: nas, afp, automount

On my MacOS 10.13.2 machine I am being inundated with network share login prompts literally every minute and they will not relent. If I ignore them and push them aside, they jump right back in my face. Pop-up ads aren't this insidious. Aside from the requirement to click "OK" to authenticate things already on your keyring, this is one my my least favorite changes in Sierra. I am not sure how I told AutoMounter that I want this network share that is on a NAS that no longer exists, but now I cannot find how to un-tell it because AutoMounter is attacking every 60 seconds. Console shows the proof:

```
Share 'homes' started to mount with URL: afp://mlitwin@diaspora(AFP)._afpovertcp._tcp.local/homes
```

This is quite possibly the worst implementation of auto_mount that I have ever seen, but that doesn't really surprise me anymore. So I think, fine... just remove it from fstab right? Wrong. It's been deprecated. I did a little reading and apparently we're supposed to use vifs now? Ok, fine. Problem is I tried that and just got an "editing error". I don't see anything explicit in /etc/auto_master either. Sigh.

**Can someone please tell me what the heck is telling AutoMounter to torture me?**

Comment: fstab can still be used to stop the auto mounting of local file systems. I do not know about remote file systems.

Comment: Check your *login items" to see if you have mounts set to automatically attach.  Also, post the contents of `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/auto_master`.

Answer (score 2):

If Google lead you here because `sudo vifs` returns

```
vifs: editing error
```

this solved it for me: [The source for `vifs`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-735/vifs.tproj/vifs.c.auto.html) shows the error in the section `/* obtain and invoke the editor */`. I have my `$EDITOR` set to use TextMate. Apparently, that doesn't work.

**Solution:**

```
EDITOR=nano sudo vifs
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am a giant doofus. I thought AutoMounter was part of MacOS when in fact it was a utility I had installed a while back and didn't configure well. I was confusing it for auto_mount. I guess it's not that far-fetched. Still, kind of embarrassing.